# How can I set styling twice in the same functions with react?

Tags: reactjs

I wish to use css-transition to animate an object:

```
<div style={this.setStyle()}>

      setStyle () {
        const style = {}
        if (this.state.fullScreen) {
          style.background = 'white'
          style.position = 'absolute'
          style.transition = 'top 2s'
          style.top = '20px'
        }

        //here I wish to set style.top = 0
        return style
      }
```

I wish to first set the `style.top = 20px` (this is where the item is already  and then re render the dom and then set the `style.top = 0` to trigger the animation. How can this be done?

```
state declaration:

 constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      active: -1,
      fullScreen: false,
      fullScreenStyle: {
        background: 'transparent',
        position: 'static',
        top: 'auto'
      }
    }
    this.flky = {}
  }

  setStyle () {
    if (this.state.fullScreen) {
      this.setState({
        fullScreenStyle.background: 'white,
        fullScreenStyle.position: 'absolute'
        fullScreenStyle.top: '20px'
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rerender the Dom you have two options:

1) by setting the state use setState.

2) by using lifecycle function that is forceUpdate()

But you have to take care before using forceupdate function because it stops other operations and invoke render function, using setState is recommended.

In this you can do one thing:

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props)
  this.state={
    style:{
        background = 'white',
        position = 'absolute',
        transition = 'top 2s',
        top:'20px'
     }           
   } 
}


<div style={this.setStyle()}>

  setStyle () {
    //you can set state as follows
    if (this.state.fullScreen) {
     this.setState({ 
      style:{background: 'white'},
      style:{position:'absolute'},
      style:{transition: 'top 2s'},
      style:{top: '20px'}
      )}
    }

    //here I wish to set style.top = 0
    else
    {
       this.setState({ style:{background: 'white'},
      style:{position:'absolute'},
      style:{transition: 'top 2s'},
      style:{top: '0px'}
      )}
     }

  }
```

Comment: How come style is moved to this.state.style?

Comment: setState sets the state to current values and call render function after that

Comment: I can't pass style.background like that, should it be style: {background: 'white'}

Comment: sorry see the edit, i forgot to remove const style={}

Comment: to access background value this.state.style.background

Comment: to set background value: this.setState({style.background:'white'})

Comment: updated the question, as far as i know you can't pass an object with the dot annotation, but I may be wrong, it throws the error unexpected token '.'

Comment: brother please share code, i will solve your problem

Comment: where are you using this.state.fullscreenstyle

Comment: code has been edited, I forgot to put comma inside setState

Comment: style.background: 'white',